# Conjecture: The sequence {$π(2n+1)!$} is equidistributed in the interval (0,1)

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, equidistribution

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

From the book *"Uniform Distribution of Sequences"* (available [here](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Ejosefdick/preprints/KuipersNied_book.pdf)) by *L. Kuipers* and *H. Niederreiter*, (from pg. 8) I found that for any irrational $\theta$, the sequence $(n\theta)$, $n = 1, 2, 3,... ,$ is uniformly distributed (or equidistributed) mod $1$ in the interval $(0,1)$, which is, in fact, Equidistribution theorem. This means that the sequence {$\pi n$}, $n=1,2,3,...,$ is equidistributed in the interval $(0,1)$, where {.} denotes the fractional part function.

It can be easily proved by **Weyl's criterion** which states that the sequence $a_n$ is equidistributed modulo $1$ if and only if for all non-zero integers h,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{2\pi ih(a_k)}=0$$
If we fix $a_n=\pi n$, it is easy to prove above criterion (proved [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Example_of_usage)).

A thought came in my mind that if we fix $a_n=\pi (2n+1)!$ , which is a subsequence of previous sequence, is *Weyl's criterion* satisfied **?**
In other words, is the sequence ($\pi (2n+1)!$), $n=1,2,...,$ equidistributed mod $1$ in the interval $(0,1)$ ? i.e, for all non-zero integers h, is the following true?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{2\pi ih\pi (2k+1)!}=0$$

I **conjecture** that the sequence {$\pi (2n+1)!$} is equidistributed in the interval $(0,1)$. This conjecture is equivalent to the affirmative answer of above two questions.

I also conjecture a **weaker** statement which is as follows:

**"**The sequence {$\pi (2n+1)!$}, $n=1,2,3,...,$ will never approach 1.**"** i.e
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\{\pi (2n+1)!\}≠1$$

where {.} is the fractional part function. Can anyone please Prove/Disprove my conjecture? Proving/disproving my weaker conjecture will also be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you believe this conjecture to be true? And what would be the point of knowing whether it's true or not?

Comment: For any monotone increasing sequence of integers $a_1 < a_2 < \dots$ and for almost any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (in the sense of Lebesgue measure), the sequence $\alpha a_n$ is equidistributed modulo 1. Therefore, unless there is a specific reason to expect otherwise, for example replacing $\pi$ by $e$ we get a sequence whose fractional part tends to 0, we would expect the sequence you describe to be equidistributed (assuming $\pi$ is a "random" number). I don't have any idea how to prove this for $\pi$ specifically though, I think the sequence $n!$ grows too fast for the usual methods to work

Comment: I see no reason to expect this to be easier than the equidistribution mod 1 of $2^n\pi$, which is a famous open problem

Comment: If $(2n+1)! \pi$ is equidistributed, then $\pi + e$ must be irrational, which is another famous open problem.  So I don't expect a proof any time soon.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What is the proof that If (2n+1)!π is equidistributed, then π+e must be irrational? From where you have known this? Please reply

Comment: @RobertIsrael, can you please suggest how can my weaker conjecture be proved/disproved?

Comment: @KavanPrajapati use series representation for $e$ for studying $n!(e+r)$ with rational $r$

Comment: @FedorPetrov, Thanks for your reply. can you please suggest how can my weaker conjecture (see in the question above) be proved?

Comment: @Kavan what does "never approach 1" mean?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, please note that {.} is the fractional part.  "Never approach 1"  means that Lim n→∞  {π(2n+1)!} ≠ 1 or 0.999...  . If we prove that  {π(2n+1)!}<0.99999999 infinitely often, then my weaker conjecture will be proved. Please help.

Comment: @KavanPrajapati but if $\pi+e$ is rational, it does approach 1